# How do I call a function from a sorted dictionary for every time the parent function is called?

Tags: python, python-3.x

(So I have a group of levels for a game, lets just say level1 - level10.

I have a function called level_up() and inside I have a dictionary that is used to group "level name" as a key to be stored in a json file and used later, and a value that is the function to be called.

So what this looks like is:

```
levels = {
         "level1":level1 #level1 is the function to be executed
         "level2":level2
         }
```

all the way down to the tenth level.

I would try to call the function like so:

```
 a = list(sorted(levels.keys())) # to sort the keys in order    
 b=level.values()
 list(sorted(b))
 b = b.pop(0)
 b()
```

This of course results in an error 
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'function'

I guess it would be easier to just make two lists but for learning purposes would like to see if I could make this function nice and concise so feel free to give any advice.

Comment: Whatever it is you're trying to do, I can say I've not seen anything like this in any python library. `list(sorted(b))` doesn't do anything, the whole thing is thrown away

Comment: You don't need to sort the values (you can't sort functions). Pop the 0th item from the sorted keys, and use it to get the 0th function from the dictionary: `levels[a[0]]()` or `levels[a.pop()]()`.

Comment: You could use an `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module to save yourself the trouble of constructing 2 lists then sorting them.

Comment: If you really needed to sort the functions, you could do `sorted(levels.values(), key=lambda x: x.__name__)`

Comment: Please give an example fo `level1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why use strings as keys? Simpler, no need to sort:

```
import sys

def level1(): print(1)  
def level2(): print(2)
def level3(): print(3) 
def win(): 
    print("you won")                
    sys.exit()

curr_lvl = 1  # start here and advance

levels = { 1:level1, 2:level2, 3:level3}

while True:
    levels.get(curr_lvl,win)() # get func and call it
    curr_lvl += 1
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
you won
```

---

If you really nead a "string" key - process it:

```
def get_level(s):
    levels = { 1:level1, 2:level2, 3:level3, 4:level4, 5:level5}
    try:
        lvl = int(s.lstrip("level"))
    except ValueError:
        pass

    return levels.get(lvl,win)

get_level("level2")()  # prints 2
```

Comment: Yeah I like that, I think it's what I really wanted to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a "sorted dictionary". Let that be clear.

Here is a possible answer, I am sure there is a more beautiful way:

```
map(lambda i: i[1], sorted(levels.items(), key=lambda i: i[0]))
```

Comment: That returns TypeError: sorted expected 1 arguments, got 2

Comment: sorry for that, forgot a key keyword